# How to remove "other..." option from color picker within HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, css

[image: I would like to remove the "Other..." button here]

How do I remove this "Other..." button?

My HTML code is as follows:
The code is supposed to update the color of the

text by selecting colors from a dropdown. I would like to restrict the user to only the colors I listed.

```
<body>
  <p>An example demonstrating the use of the <code>&lt;input type="color"&gt;</code>
     control.</p>

  <label for="colorWell">Color:</label>
  <input type="color" value="#ff0000" id="colorWell" list="presetColors">
 <datalist id="presetColors">
   <option>#ff0000</option>
   <option>#00ff00</option>
   <option>#0000ff</option>
 </datalist>

  <p>Watch the paragraph colors change when you adjust the color picker.
     As you make changes in the color picker, the first paragraph's
     color changes, as a preview (this uses the <code>input</code>
     event). When you close the color picker, the <code>change</code>
     event fires, and we detect that to change every paragraph to
     the selected color.</p>
  <script src="scripts.js"></script>
</body>
```

My JavaScript code is as follows:

```
var colorWell;
var defaultColor = "#0000ff";

window.addEventListener("load", startup, false);

function startup() {
  colorWell = document.querySelector("#colorWell");
  colorWell.value = defaultColor;
  colorWell.addEventListener("input", updateFirst, false);
  colorWell.addEventListener("change", updateAll, false);
  colorWell.select();
}

function updateFirst(event) {
  var p = document.querySelector("p");
  console.log(event.target.value);
  if (p) {
    p.style.color = event.target.value;
  }
}

function updateAll(event) {
  document.querySelectorAll("p").forEach(function(p) {
    p.style.color = event.target.value;
  });
}

    <label for="colorWell">Color:</label>
  <input type="color" value="#ff0000" id="colorWell" list="presetColors">
 <datalist id="presetColors">
   <option>#ff0000</option>
   <option>#00ff00</option>
   <option>#0000ff</option>
 </datalist>
```

Comment: That HTML doesn't contain an "other" button. Show all relevant code, including any libraries you might be using.

Comment: This is apparently Chrome-specific (Firefox ignores the datalist), and I don't think there's any way to change that built-in popup, much like you cannot style select options. If you want to get rid of the button, you have to make your own color buttons using custom code.

Answer (score -2):

I suggest you delete from source code but if you can't find this button in source code, you can remove with javascript `remove()` method.

```js
function remove(){
document.getElementById('target').remove();
}
```

```html
<button id="target">Target</button>
<br><br>
<button id="remover" onclick="remove()">Remove Button</button>
```

if the button has no id, you can solve it with such a method with jquery:

```
$(function(){
 setInterval(function(){
  $('button').each(function(){
  var target = $(this);
  if(target.text() == 'Other...' || target.val() == 'Other...'){
   target.remove();
  }
  });
 }, 300); // 300 ms. you can change time range.
});
```

> if the button is loaded once with document, you don't need to use the
>   setInterval method

Comment: This is not possible since this is an html tag. The "Other" button is created by the browser at runtime. Their is not HTML created by the user.